# Write to the Apache ErrorLog (404) when using RewriteRule/PHP

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Using what seems to be the fairly standard:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

All requests go to the index.php file to handle (unless Apache can see the file on disk already).

But if the script determines that the requested URL does not exist (404), how can you log this in the Apache ErrorLog?

The script returns with a 404 header:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

But the error log remains empty, while the access log shows the 404:

```
192.168.2.2 - - [13/Aug/2012:10:39:35 +0100] "GET /404 HTTP/1.1" 404 32958
```

As the server is hosting several websites, I would like them all to use the same mechanism to record these errors (rather than having to write to a second log file in PHP, or trying to get PHP to fopen/fread/fclose that same file that Apache may already have a lock on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write to stderr, as apache will catch this and append it to its own error log:

```
$stderr = fopen('php://stderr', 'w'); 
fwrite($stderr, 'My error'); 
fclose($stderr);
```

You can also unset the `error_log` directive in `php.ini`, which would result in every PHP error to be appended to `ErrorLog`.

Comment: Thats great, didn't realise that if you wrote to stderr it would appear in the Apache error logs... do you know if its possible to match the format Apache uses with ErrorLogFormat?

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot write the format within PHP? I mean, how often does the `ErrorLogFormat` really change?

Comment: Probably never, and thats what I've done for now... but was thinking it would be nice to only have that format defined once (rather than one for Apache, and one for each website that ends up using this).

Comment: Well, it is possible to "hack" it a bit. If you make a file, `definitions.php` where you place `define ('APACHE_ERRORLOG_FORMAT', 'someFormatHere')`, then you could use the php.ini directive `auto_prepend_file = /path/to/definitions.php`. The file with the constant, would be usable by all PHP installations that uses the php.ini as definitions.php is prepended to every PHP file.

Comment: Thanks @DavidS, that is one way around it... I think I'll stick to your original suggestion of just specifying the format in the script, and assume its at least roughly the same as the one used by Apache though, just because I want to keep the number of hacks down.

Answer (score 1):

Have also found that writing to "php://stderr" on a `<VirtualHost>` won't write to that virtual hosts `ErrorLog`, and instead goes to the main Apache error log.

However there is also the PHP function error_log().

```
error_log('File does not exist: ' . XXX, 4);
```

The 4 means it goes to Apache (SAPI logging handler), rather than the php `error_log` file.

http://php.net/error_log